# Repeating background and diagonal shape

Tags: css

I have a design which features this sort of stripey strip that goes across horizontally, like a divider between sections.

My problem is that I don't know how to do this in a way that will be responsive / flexible width.

I'm thinking the only way to do is would be to have a repeating background for the stripey bit and then a div over the top, which is cut on an angle .. if that makes any sense.

[image]

Comment: Look into `SVG` (Scaleable Vector Graphic) which will be very responsive and lite weight on the file size.

Answer (score 1):

Not the prettiest thing, but this should get you started -

HTML

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="border grey-stripe"></div>

    <section class="bg-black">

        <div>
            <p>TEXT</p>
        </div>

    </section>

    <div class="border red-stripe"></div>

     <section class="bg-grey">

        <div>
            <p>TEXT</p>
        </div>

    </section>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    border:1px solid;
}
section div{
    padding-top:89px;
}

.bg-black {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-89px;
    z-index:1;
    background:#000;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
}

.bg-grey{
   position:relative;
    margin-top:-89px;
    z-index:1;
    background:#ccc;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
}
.border {
    height:89px;
    z-index:2;
    position:relative;
}

.grey-stripe {
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/J2brM1S.png) no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}

.red-stripe {
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/ewqj4QB.png) no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markob83/4jh2v/2/)